# Typing hint for abstract class method that returns class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm getting type checker errors on the following code, I would love to understand how to resolve the error.

The following base class has an abstract class method, I want that every child class that inherits from it will implement a `decode` function that returns an instance of the child class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar


TMetricBase = TypeVar("TMetricBase", bound="MetricBase")


class MetricBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, element: str) -> None:
        pass  # pragma: no cover

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> TMetricBase:
        pass  # pragma: no cover
```

Child class looks like the following

```
import json
from typing import Any, Callable, List, Mapping, Optional
from something import MetricBase, TMetricBase


class DiscreteHistogramMetric(MetricBase):
    def __init__(self, histogram: Optional[Mapping[str, int]]) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._histogram = dict(histogram) if histogram else {}

    def add(self, element: str) -> None:
        self._histogram[element] = self._histogram.get(element, 0) + 1

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> "DiscreteHistogramMetric":
        json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
        histogram_map = json_obj["DiscreteHistogramMetric"]
        return cls(histogram=histogram_map)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Return type of "decode" incompatible with supertype "MetricBase"
```

When changing `decode`'s return type to `TMetricBase`, I get the following error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "DiscreteHistogramMetric", expected "TMetricBase")
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to annotate that a classmethod returns an instance of that class](//stackoverflow.com/q/51647747) ?

Answer (score 14):

The error has to do with how you're having just a single TypeVar in the return type of `decode`. It's unclear what that would mean, exactly -- you're more or less trying to declare that every single subclass of `MetricBase` needs to support returning any other arbitrary subclass of `MetricBase`, which it'll somehow magically infer based on how that function is being called.

This isn't really something that's possible to do in Python.

What you'll need to do instead is one of the following:

1. Give up and not use TypeVars
2. Make `MetricBase` a generic class and have your subclasses inherit a parameterized version of `MetricBase`.
3. Use `TMetricBase` in the `decode` parameters in some way. (This way, we can actually deduce what the return type ought to be).

I'm assuming you've already considered the first solution and rejected it: it would make our program type check, but would also make the `decode` method somewhat useless/require some clunky casting.

The second solution looks something like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

TMetricBase = TypeVar("TMetricBase", bound="MetricBase")

class MetricBase(ABC, Generic[TMetricBase]):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> TMetricBase:
        pass

class DiscreteHistogramMetric(MetricBase['DiscreteHistogramMetric']):
    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> "DiscreteHistogramMetric":
        pass
```

By having `DiscreteHistogramMetric` subclass `MetricBase[DiscreteHistogramMetric]` instead of just `MetricBase` directly, we can actually constrain the typevar to something meaningful.

This solution is still a little clunky though -- having to subclass `MetricBase` requires us to start using generics wherever we use MetricBase which is pretty annoying.

The third solution on the surface initially sounds even clunkier: are we going to add in some extra dummy third param or some nonsense? But it turns out there's a nice trick we can use -- we can use [generic selfs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) to annotate the `cls` variable!

Normally, the type of that variable is inferred and doesn't need to be annotated, but in this case, it's helpful to do so: we can use information about what exactly `cls` is to help produce a more refined return type.

Here's what it looks like:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Type

TMetricBase = TypeVar("TMetricBase", bound="MetricBase")

class MetricBase(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def decode(cls: Type[TMetricBase], json_str: str) -> TMetricBase:
        pass

class DiscreteHistogramMetric(MetricBase):
    def __init__(self, something: str) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls: Type[TMetricBase], json_str: str) -> TMetricBase:
        # Note that we need to use create the class by using `cls` instead of
        # using `DiscreteHistogramMetric` directly.
        return cls("blah")
```

It's a bit unfortunate that we need to continue using TypeVars within the subclass instead of defining it more simply the way you did in your question -- I believe this behavior is [a bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2511).

However, it *does* do the trick: doing `DiscreteHistogramMetric.decode("blah")` will return a `TMetricBase` as expected.

And unlike the first approach, the messiness is at least pretty well-confined to the `decode` method and doesn't require you to start using generics wherever you're also using `MetricBase` classes.

Answer (score 6):

**Note: [this is available in MyPy 1.0 and up](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2023/02/mypy-10-released.html).**

[PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) introduces the "`Self` Type", which should be available in Python 3.11, and backport-able via `typing-extensions` package.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Self


class MetricBase(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> Self:
        pass


class DiscreteHistogramMetric(MetricBase):
    def __init__(self, something: str) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, json_str: str) -> Self:
        return cls("blah")
```